# Not able to add a package same as the workspace name in a yarn workspace

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am using yarn workspaces in one of my projects and I want to add a library *react-table* from npm repository. I already have a workspace *react-table*. In one of my other workspace I want to refer to *react-table* from npm repository.
Every time I do `yarn add react-table` it refer to the workspace but not the npm repository.
How can I achieve the above?

Comment: I generally prefix my workspaces with a private organisation scope https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes So I'll do @projectname/react-table for the workspace so there are no conflicts - it also makes it easier to identify in the code what is a workspace and what is a standard package